# に usage and meaning in 旅行代金の請求書の控えを2枚目に送った

Tags: translation, particle-に

旅行代金の請求書の控えを2枚目**に**送った This に here, what does it mean.

Here's the context　(The question doesn't appear in picture below)

[image]

There's a context saying 枚数:　本状を含めて2枚 ,so I think the bill has 2 pages.

I tried translating 旅行代金の請求書の控えを2枚目**に**送った and it was like " sent travel bill duplicate **as** the second page"

PS. In this post I use "Travel bill" as 旅行代金の請求書, Duplicate as 控え because I'm not good at English. Sorry for that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2枚目**に** 'on the second page' or 'attached to the second page'.
Seems like a standard usage of に to me. You could translate as follows:

> 旅行代金の請求書の控えを2枚目に送った
>
> I sent a copy of the travel bill, attached to the second page.